# how to send a select query to SQL Azure federation root from SQL Azure federation members?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Let's suppose we have some federation members and 1 federation root, and the federation root has a table called "common".

Once a day, I'd like to run a join query between the common table (in the federation root), and a table in a federation member. The query skeleton looks as follows:

(in a federation member...)

SELECT * FROM FED_MEMBER_TABLE
WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM common)

// note that the 'common' table is in the federation root, not the federation member

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik, no.

if its a common table among federation members, you should have it as a reference table in all the federation members.